# how to open new activity that is showing only the content of the message when I click on list item

Tags: java, android, listview

```
package com.company.messagesystem;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AllMessages extends Activity {
private List<Message> _messages = new ArrayList<Message>();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    populateMessageList();
    _messages = MessagesDataSource.getAll();
    populateListView();
    //registerClickCallBack();

    Button newMessageBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_message_btn);
    newMessageBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent("com.company.messagesystem.NEWMESSAGE"));              
        }           
    });
}

private void populateMessageList() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    cal.setTime(new Date()); 
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -1); 
    Date date1 = cal.getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");          
    String date= null;
    date = format1.format(date1);

    cal.setTime(new Date());  
    Date currDate2 = cal.getTime();         
    String date2= null;
    date2 = format1.format(currDate2);

    cal.setTime(new Date()); 
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -2); 
    Date currDate3 = cal.getTime();         
    String date3= null;
    date3 = format1.format(currDate3);

    cal.setTime(new Date()); 
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -3); 
    Date currDate4 = cal.getTime();         
    String date4= null;
    date4 = format1.format(currDate4);

    cal.setTime(new Date()); 
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -2); 
    Date currDate5 = cal.getTime();        
    String date5= null;
    date5 = format1.format(currDate5);

    cal.setTime(new Date()); 
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,- 4); 
    Date currDate6 = cal.getTime();         
    String date6= null;
    date6 = format1.format(currDate6);

    cal.setTime(new Date()); 
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,- 4); 
    Date currDate7 = cal.getTime();         
    String date7= null;
    date7 = format1.format(currDate7);

    MessagesDataSource.add(new Message(1, "Speed to hight", "You must to slow down! ", date,"Georgi Ivanov", R.drawable.ic_launcher, true, true));
    MessagesDataSource.add(new Message(1, "Speed to low", "You must to speed up!",date2,"Maria Petrova", R.drawable.ic_launcher,false, true));
    MessagesDataSource.add(new Message(1, "Delay", "You are gonna be late", date3,"Georgi Ivanov",R.drawable.ic_launcher, true, true));
    MessagesDataSource.add(new Message(1, "Traffic", "There is congestion after 30km", date4, "Maria Petrova",R.drawable.ic_launcher, true, true)); 
    MessagesDataSource.add(new Message(1, "Delay", "You are gonna be late", date5,"Georgi Ivanov",R.drawable.ic_launcher, true, true));
    MessagesDataSource.add(new Message(1, "Traffic", "There is congestion after 30km", date6, "Maria Petrova",R.drawable.ic_launcher, true, true));
    MessagesDataSource.add(new Message(1, "Speed to hight", "You must to slow down! ", date,"Georgi Ivanov", R.drawable.ic_launcher, true, true));
    MessagesDataSource.add(new Message(1, "Speed to low", "You must to speed up!",date7,"Maria Petrova", R.drawable.ic_launcher,false, true));
}

private void populateListView() {
    ArrayAdapter<Message> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.messageslistView);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void registerClickCallBack() {
    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.messageslistView);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        }
    });     


private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Message>{
    public MyListAdapter(){
        super(AllMessages.this,R.layout.item_view,_messages);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemView = convertView;
        if(itemView == null){
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);
        }

        //Find the message to work with
        Message currentMessage = _messages.get(position);

        //Fill the view         
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
        imageView.setImageResource(currentMessage.getIconId());

        //Content
        TextView contentText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_textContent);
        contentText.setText(currentMessage.getContent());

        //Subject
        TextView subjectText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_textSubject);
        subjectText.setText(currentMessage.getSubject());

        //Date
        TextView dateText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_textDate);
        dateText.setText(currentMessage.getDate().toString());

        return itemView;
    }   
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
}
```

}

```
This is the class Message:

public class Message {
public int Id;
private String subject;
private String content;
private String date;
private String sender;
private int iconId;
private boolean isRead;
private boolean isRecieved;

public Message(int id,String subject,String content,String date,String sender, int iconId, boolean isRead,boolean isRecieved){
    super();
    this.Id = id;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.content = content;
    this.date = date;
    this.sender = sender;
    this.iconId = iconId;
    this.isRead = isRead;
    this.isRead = isRead;
}

public int getId() {
    return Id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.Id = id;
}

public String getSubject() {
    return subject;
}

public void setSubject(String subject) {
    this.subject = subject;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getSender() {
    return sender;
}

public void setSender(String sender) {
    this.sender = sender;
}

public int getIconId() {
    return iconId;
}

public void setIconId(int iconId) {
    this.iconId = iconId;
}

public boolean getIsRead() {
    return isRead;
}

public void setIsRead(boolean isRead) {
    this.isRead = isRead;
}

public boolean getIsRecieved() {
    return isRecieved;
}

public void setIsRecieved(boolean isRecieved) {
    this.isRecieved = isRecieved;
}
```

}

I want when I click message from the list view to open new activity with only the content of the              massage.I don't want to make activities for every message, I want to use the same activity for every   messages.If somebody can help me with this....

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the content of the `ListView` items. If it's just free text message, then just set the `onItemClickListener` in your `ListView` to start a new Activity and pass the text in the intent when starting the activity. Inside the new activity, get the intent that started it, get your message from the intent, display the message in your activity. Your new activity layout would probably be just a `TextView` that captures the whole activity.

That way, it's one activity, and once you go back to the list, the activity is destroyed and you started it again with a different item. The key is to pass the data from the `ListView` and pass it in the `Activity`.

//Edit here is a simple example that shows how to pass the data in the intent:

http://hmkcode.com/android-passing-data-to-another-activities/